# std::deque: How is push_front( ) and push_back( ) possible in O(1)?

Tags: c++, deque, std

I know `std::deque` is useful when we have to insert at both end or delete at both end. I have a doubt on `push_front()` and `push_back()` time complexities.

How it is O(1) ? Is it amortized analysis or something else ?

How it is internally implemented ??